# Rails many-to-many polymorphic create mulitple

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, polymorphic-associations

So I've created a Category model for my Questions model. I've also created a Tag model for a polymorphic relationship so that a question can have many categories and a category can have many questions.

I'm having trouble completing the process whereby when a Question is created and Categories selected, the Categories associated with the Question are also saved. There seems to be a missing connection between submitting the form and creating the Tags.

Here are my models:

**question.rb**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :tags, :as => :taggable, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :categories, :through => :tags

end
```

**tag.rb**

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :category

end
```

**Category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :tags, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :questions, :through => :tags, :source => :taggable, :source_type => 'Question'

end
```

**Question form:**

> ```
> <%= f.input :question, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }%>
> </div>
>
> <div class="form-group">
> <%= f.input :category_ids, collection: Category.all, :input_html => {multiple: true, class: 'form-control' } %>
> </div>
>
> <%= f.fields_for :choices do |b| %>
> <div class="form-group">
> <%= b.input :choice, input_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
>
>  </div>
>
> <% end %>
> ```
>
> ```
> <%= f.button :submit, :class => "btn btn-primary"%>
> ```

**Question controller create action**

> def create
>       @question = current_user.questions.new(question_params)
>
> ```
> respond_to do |format|
>   if @question.save
>     format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question was successfully created.' }
>     format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @question }
>   else
>     format.html { render action: 'new' }
>     format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
>   end
> end   end
> ```

When submitting the form, the category ids are submitted like so: "category_ids"=>["", "2", "3"]

I feel that the missing link would be to create a method like so

```
def create_tag (category_id, question_id)
    t = Tag.new
    t.taggable = Question.find(question_id)
    t.category = Category.find(category_id)
    t.save

end
```

But I'm unsure where to best place this or how to connect it in the create action and successfully create the proper associations.

Also this method would create only 1 category, so I'd need to loop through the category ids to create multiple.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this code?

```
def create
  @question = current_user.questions.new(question_params)
  if @question.save
    params[:question][:category_ids].select{ |x| x.present? }.each do |category_id|
      tag = Tag.new(taggable: @question, category_id: category_id)
      if tag.save
      else
        something_went_wrong = tag
      end
    end
  else
    something_went_wrong = @question
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    if something_went_wrong.blank?
      format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @question }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: something_went_wrong.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

The things with this code are:

- Each Tag created is just a link between Question & Category, there is no actual name for the Tag.
- Even if one Tag does not pass the validations (like a uniqueness constraint), the others valid tags will be created, but will still display errors. You may want to check if all tags are valid before creating them.

Comment: Thanks MrYoshiji. For some reason the form is submitting a nil category_id "" at the start of the array. I have to investigate this before the code is fully run.

Comment: It is a normal behavior of Rails, it's like with the double-generated check_box fields with opposite values: Rails adds this empty string in order to let you "fill" the select with no value. If you don't select any value, you still want the object to be updated, right? If you de-select all the categories of a Question, it should remove the relations. Well if you submit the value of a Select that has no selected value, then this params will be ignored: Rails keeps an empty entry in this param to allow you to set to "none" the value of this select box.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I sill want the object updated if no category value is selected. Unfortunately I get the error 'private method `select' called for nil:NilClass'  when submitting this code

Comment: I updated my answer @BenG, the thing is that the question_params method does not return an entry for the `category_ids` key, permit it in your strong parameters or try with the syntax I used

Comment: To be a pain and ask another question relating to this code, do you know why I can  access a questions categories (Question.first.categories) but when I try to access a Categories questions (Category.first.questions) I get the error 'column questions.taggable_type does not exist'?